# Is there a way to make pandas read_csv function faster

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

Currently, I am working with a file that is big (around 45GB)
I am trying to load the file using pandas read_csv function, however, it is taking forever just to loading the file. Is there a way to fasten this process?

I was thinking of splitting the file into few chunks and loading them using multiprocessing.

Or is there a better way of doing this?

*edit: I think using chunksize param in read_csv() is the best option*

Answer (score 2):

You can use `modin.pandas` [refer this link](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) where they show the difference in performance for `read_csv`.

In my experience of using modin, it was faster than pandas. But haven't tried with 45GB data. You can give it a try

You can also try using `Dask` [click here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)